# @Around Aspect in Spring AOP throwing Null Pointer Exception

Tags: spring, spring-aop

Can someone help me out figuring why my @Around advice throws a Null Pointer Exception here. I have made sure that my advice returns an Object same as the method to proceed, yet I am getting the exception.

```
@Aspect
public class BasicAuthAspect 
{

    @Around("execution(* *..impl.PreferenceImpl.*(..))") 
    public Object auth(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
        log.debug("Inside Basic Auth check method..");
        ServletRequestAttributes requestAttributes=null;
        requestAttributes=(ServletRequestAttributes)
      RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
        if(requestAttributes!=null){
        request =requestAttributes.getRequest();

         Object[] signatureArgs = joinPoint.getArgs();
            try {
                return (Response) joinPoint.proceed(signatureArgs);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                return Response.status(HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED).build();
            }
    }

        }
        else{
            return Response.status(HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED).build();
        }


      }

}
```

Here is my method to proceed(PreferenceImpl.java):

```
@Override
    public Response postPreferences( String preference) {


        String responseReturned=searchDAO.postPreference( XSSUtils.normalize(preference));
        if(responseReturned!=null)
        response=Response.status("success").build();
        else
        response=Response.status("failure").build();
        return response;    
        }
```

Here goes the error log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:556)[:1.7.0_80]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.getAuthorizationPolicyFromMessage(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:163)[173:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:2.7.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.setupMessage(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:349)[173:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:2.7.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.setupMessage(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:258)[173:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:2.7.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.serviceRequest(JettyHTTPDestination.java:345)[179:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty:2.7.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.doService(JettyHTTPDestination.java:319)[179:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty:2.7.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPHandler.handle(JettyHTTPHandler.java:72)[179:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty:2.7.3]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1040)[79:org.eclipse.jetty.server:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:976)[79:org.eclipse.jetty.server:7.6.8.v20121106]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have several problems here:

- Your pointcut intercepts all `PreferenceImpl` methods, but it seems you only want to catch a single one. I suggest you make the pointcut more specific.
- You are assuming return type `Response` in the advice method, but your pointcut assumes `*` and the advice method itself returns `Object`, so theoretically another method could return another type and the cast would fail (see first problem).
- You are trying to provide arguments to `proceed()`, but that is actually not necessary. So just remove the `getArgs()` stuff, you do not need it.

If despite my hints you still have problems, let me know and I can provide some sample code. BTW, maybe you want to read a basic Spring AOP tutorial. :-)

Comment: Thanks kriegaex. I think you pointed out valid potential problems. I have made the necessary corrections. Cleaning up my advice method as per your suggestions did help. Thanks a lot!